# When I inspect-element, after <img> tags, Firefox inserts "::before </img>" & Chrome inserts "== $0"

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

### While these insertions are not there in source-code.

---

Also my images don't load even though they are there on host server. Don't know if this problem is related to insertions mentioned in title of my post or some other reason!

[image: screenshot of firefox inspect element]
I tried deleting images from server and upload again. Page works fine when opened from computer but same files when uploaded to server, don't show images.! Any advice is much appreciated.

Update: I restored firefox to factory defaults and that did the trick. Now images are showing. and also "::before" is not being inserted in inspect-element window. But a closing  tag is still inserted. If someone could please explain the probable cause that stop images from showing, before factory-reset was done? Now I'll work on chrome, as it is also not showing the images

Comment: Update: 
I restored firefox to factory defaults and that did the trick. Now images are showing. and also "::before" is not being inserted in inspect-element window. But a closing </img> tag is still inserted. 

If someone could please explain the probable cause that stop images from showing, before factory-reset was done? Now I'll work on chrome, as it is also not showing the images.

Answer (score 1):

- `$0` indicates that this is the "current" element being inspected. You can type `$0` into the chrome console and it will be the HTMLImageElement you are inspecting. See [Chrome DevTools API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference#section-1)

Comment: Thanks!
Any idea on firefox inserting "::before </img>" after all of my <img> tags in inspect-element?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same thing when trying to put content in the `<img>` tag with javascript.
When I use the img tag without src parameter being set, same thing happens. As soon as I declared at least `src="";`in Firefox it shows proper unclosed `<img>` tag without the `::before`.

*I'm going to search for more info on this to expand the answer, just wanted to clarify - are your img tags possibly declared without the src attribute and then worked with after in some fashion? (<- this is a comment to the original question, I can't comment.)*